# Querying missing rows within a group in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table that looks something like this:

```
with base_tbl as (
  select 
    "A" as name, 123 as roll_num, "chemistry" as subject, 1 as slot
  union all
  select 
    "A" as name, 123 as roll_num, "chemistry" as subject, 2 as slot
  union all
  select 
    "A" as name, 123 as roll_num, "physics" as subject, 1 as slot
  union all

  select 
    "B" as name, 234 as roll_num, "physics" as subject, 1 as slot
  union all
  select 
    "B" as name, 234 as roll_num, "physics" as subject, 2 as slot
)
```

The column *subject* can only take values `physics` or `chemistry` and the column *slot* can take values `1` or `2`.

Looking for recommendations on how I can flag students who have either one of the subjects missing or a slot missing: In the example above, expected output would be:

| student | roll_num | subject_missing | slot_missing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 123 | physics | 2 |
| B | 234 | chemistry | 1 |
| B | 234 | chemistry | 2 |

My real data has about ~170m rows, with several other grouping columns (student and roll_num here). Essentially I am trying to gauge the "completeness" of the dataset.

---

Compilation screengrab:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit optimized version of original answer:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * EXCEPT(subject, slot) FROM base_tbl) t,
       UNNEST(["physics", "chemistry"]) subject, UNNEST([1, 2]) slot

EXCEPT DISTINCT

SELECT * FROM base_tbl WHERE subject IN ("physics", "chemistry");
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a **set** operation,

```sql
SELECT t.* REPLACE(sj AS subject, sl AS slot)
  FROM base_tbl t,UNNEST(["physics", "chemistry"]) sj, UNNEST([1, 2]) sl
EXCEPT DISTINCT
SELECT * FROM base_tbl;
```

output:

[image]

Comment: this is obviously the way to go! :o) nice job! voted

Comment: Elegant and simple. Thanks Jaytiger and Mikhail!

Comment: The two tables I want to compare are really large (each 150m rows). Arrays `sj` and `subject` are of size (2, 1500) respectively. Bigquery takes too long to execute (>40mins). I looked at the stage-wise execution, but not sure if I can optimize the query any further. Thoughts?

Comment: I looked at the execution logs, attaching logs for the longest stage in the original post.

Comment: @Ashwin, not sure I clearly understood your comments but would you try another answer I posted ?

Comment: The new solution is significantly faster, and runs within a minute. Thanks again, Jaytiger!!

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(missing_subjects_slots) 
from (
  select name, roll_num, 
    array(
      select as struct subject as subject_missing, slot as slot_missing
      from unnest(['chemistry', 'physics']) subject, unnest([1, 2]) slot
      where not (subject, slot) in (
        select as struct subject, slot
        from t1.subjects_slots
      )
    ) missing_subjects_slots
  from (
    select name, roll_num, 
      array_agg(struct(subject, slot)) subjects_slots,
    from base_tbl
    group by name, roll_num
  ) t1
) t2, t2.missing_subjects_slots
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: most likely can be refactored to something less verbose - leaving it to Op